# The first a tag didn't work because of no attribute using Html32TextWriter

Tags: vb.net

I created a hyperlink using Html32TextWriter. I loop through the dataview to add the  tag. The first hyperlink didn't have attribute. Would someone show me what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

There is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports System.Data

Partial Class test
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

Public Function process() As StringWriter
    Dim tb As New DataTable
    tb.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    tb.Columns.Add("Category", GetType(String))
    tb.Rows.Add("Beer", "Drink")
    tb.Rows.Add("Apple", "Fruit")
    tb.Rows.Add("Orange", "Fruit")
    Dim dv As New DataView(tb)
    dv.Sort = "Name ASC"
    Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()

    returnTextbyGroup(dv, sw)

    Return sw
End Function

Private Sub returnTextbyGroup(ByVal dv As DataView, ByRef sw As StringWriter)


    Dim strHref As String = "list/"
    Using ht As Html32TextWriter = New Html32TextWriter(sw)
        '' Create the div.

        ht.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)

        ht.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontWeight, "bold")
        ht.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Label)
        ht.Write("List:")
        ht.RenderEndTag()  'close label
        ht.Write("<br/>")

        For Each row As DataRowView In dv

            ' Create the a.
            ht.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A)
            ht.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, strHref & "/" & row.Item("Name").ToString)
            ht.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Target, "_blank")
            ht.Write(row.Item("Name").ToString)
            ht.RenderEndTag()
            ht.Write("<br/>")


        Next
        ht.RenderEndTag() 'end div


    End Using




End Sub

End Class
```

there is my asp page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%=process()%>
    </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to put the attribute code before RenderBeginTag.

```
For Each row As DataRowView In dv

        ' Create the a.
        ht.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, strHref & "/" & row.Item("Name").ToString)
        ht.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Target, "_blank")
        ht.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A)            
        ht.Write(row.Item("Name").ToString)
        ht.RenderEndTag()
        ht.Write("<br/>")


    Next
```